# why in react contexttype must be specified when use context?

Tags: reactjs

[In react context doc](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html), when a child access when contextType is not assigned, the context is empty. It seems that it is necessary for parent and child to assign the propType for using context.

Props also have propTypes but they are not necessary, then why necessary for context? Is it just designed for using context more safely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The answer to your question is already on the page you have referred.

> If you want your application to be stable, don't use context. It is an
>   experimental API and it is likely to break in future releases of
>   React.

React doesn't want you to use context unless you know what you are doing. This is the reason it's required to explicitly define `contextTypes` when we need to use context.

In contrast, [`propTypes`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html) is a just type checking tool comes with React which make sure developer has passed all necessary props correctly. It does nothing but shows some warnings if you haven't passed props correctly. Also, `propTypes` type checking only work in developer mode and get removed in production builds. From React v15.5 `propTypes` is deprecated and has been moved to a [separate package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types).